# Is there a chance I will be issued Schengen visa with longer validity than my travel/health insurance?

Tags: visas, schengen, insurance, applications

I am planning to apply for a Schengen visa and I am hoping that I will be granted a longer duration of stay. This will be my second time to apply. In my first Schengen visa, I was only given 10 days duration of stay which was valid only from and until the dates indicated on the airline ticket I submitted. Back then I also bought insurance with coverage from those dates only.

Now I am kinda hoping I would be given a visa with longer validity and/or duration of stay. I already bought my plane tickets for a two-week trip. If I buy an insurance which covers me only for the days of my travel, is there a chance that the embassy will still issue a visa which is valid for longer than 2 weeks? I am also thinking that maybe if I buy an insurance with a longer period of coverage say 90 or 180 days then maybe the embassy would give me a visa with longer validity. What do you guys think?

Comment: As I explained below they should not care at all about insurance, for multiple reasons. But to the extent they do, signalling you are hoping for a longer visa might actually a bad idea as it contradicts the rest of your application (which is structured around a specific trip) and could undermine it. Ultimately, it suggests you are not being entirely truthful about your plans and intent.

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure I understand what you are hoping for or that your strategy fully makes sense but I don't think insurance matters that much:

- If the consulate thinks you should get a visa for this one trip, it is likely to be a single-entry visa with parameters (validity, duration of stay, etc.) tracking the itinerary and evidence you submitted. In that case the ticket, accommodation and planned itinerary matter just as much if not more than insurance.
- If the consulate thinks you are a trusted traveller that should be allowed to come back to the Schengen area without being screened every time, you might get a multiple-entry visa with a long validity. In that case you are only required to have insurance for the first trip when applying for the visa so the issue is moot.

It's recommended for consulates to grant a visa with a few more days to provide some buffer in case of unplanned difficulties (e.g. with transportation) but it makes no sense for them to randomly allow a much longer duration of stay if they don't think you fall in the second category.